# Create table using json file

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create a new simple table at bigquery console but I go this error: Error while reading data,error message: Failed to parse JSON: Unknown token type;Unexpected token;Parser terminated before end of string.

Here is the Json data:
{"name": "omar", "id": 1, "salary": 30000, "age": 21, "address": "Hyderabad"}
{"name": "ram", "id": 2, "salary": 40000, "age": 30, "address": "Hyderabad"}
{"name": "robbin", "id": 3, "salary": 35000, "age": 25, "address": "Hyderabad"}

Thanks

Comment: The data you posted is not valid JSON. Assuming it's an array it should look like this: `[{"name": "omar", "id": 1, "salary": 30000, "age": 21, "address": "Hyderabad"},
{"name": "ram", "id": 2, "salary": 40000, "age": 30, "address": "Hyderabad"},
{"name": "robbin", "id": 3, "salary": 35000, "age": 25, "address": "Hyderabad"}]`

Comment: I had no issue loading this data into BQ with the following command :
    bq load --autodetect --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON mydataset.test data.json

With data.json containing the data you provided (newline delimited which is what BQ expects).
Can you maybe share the command you used ?